# How to simplify $\newcommand{\bigk}{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{f_k(s)}{g_k(s)}\right)^{-1}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, continued-fractions, theta-functions, dirichlet-series

I'd like to simplify

$$\newcommand{\bigk}{\mathop{\huge\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}B(s)=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{f_{k}(s)}{f_{k}(s)}\right)^{-1}$$ to something of the form $$B(s)=\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{F_{k}(s)}{G_{k}(s)}$$

This is related to the question "[Arithmetic of continued fractions, does it exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76036/arithmetic-of-continued-fractions-does-it-exist)".

---

**Motivation**:

Consider the following representation of a function
$$
f(z)= 1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \prod_{k=1}^{n}f_{k}(z) \right)
$$
Using *Euler's continued fraction formula*, this function can have the following representation
$$
  f(z)= \cfrac{1}{
          1- \cfrac{f_{1}(z)}{
          1+f_{1}(z)- \cfrac{f_{2}(z)}{
          1+f_{2}(z)- \cfrac{f_{3}(z)}{
          1+f_{3}(z) - \ddots}}}}
$$
Now consider the Jacobi theta function
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\vartheta_{4}(0,x)+1)=1-x+x^{4}-x^{9}+x^{16}\cdots
$$
and the fact that
$$
n^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)
$$
We can represent the theta function as 
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\vartheta_{4}(0,x)+1)=1-x+x^{1+3}-x^{1+3+5}+x^{1+3+5+7}\cdots
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\vartheta_{4}(0,x)+1)= 1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left( \prod_{k=1}^{n}x^{2k-1} \right)
$$
so $\frac{1}{2}(\vartheta_{4}(0,x)+1)$ has the following continued fraction representation
$$
  \frac{1}{2}(\vartheta_{4}(0,x)+1)= \cfrac{1}{
          1+ \cfrac{x}{
          1-x+ \cfrac{x^{3}}{
          1-x^{3}+ \cfrac{x^{5}}{
          1-x^{5} + \ddots}}}}
$$
Now [remember](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73354) that the Riemann's zeta function can be represented by
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{A(s)}{B(s)}$$
with 
$$
B(s)=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{2}\left(\vartheta_{4}(0,\frac{1}{p^{z}})+1\right) 
$$
and $A(s)$ convergent for $\Re{(s)}>\frac{1}{4}$

We have then that $B(s)$ is an infinite product of continued fractions
$$
  B(s)=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^{-(2k-1)s}}{1-p^{-(2k-1)s}}\right)^{-1}\ \
$$

where $p\in\mathbb{P}$ are prime numbers.

**Finally my question, could someone find a representation for $B(s)$ as a single continued fraction?**

Thanks.

Comment: What does K do?

Comment: @Alizter, [Gauss notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction)